# Choose a random item based on probabilities

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple web app to help me with learning vocabulary.

A have an array of words (every word is an object - term + definition). Right now I'm randomly choosing a word, it's gonna show me the definition and I have to write the term. Whenever I submit the term, it's gonna show me if I was right or wrong and then randomly choose another word.

The problem with this is that it's possible that I'll be getting some words very often, although I know them very well, while others (that I might be having a problem with) won't show up much.

I would like to choose a word from the array of words so that the words that I know won't show as often, while the words that I haven't done yet or I've been answering wrong will show up with higher frequency. (But I would still like to keep some kind of randomness)

I'm using this function to get a random index of a word in the array of words:

```
const newIndex = () =>{
   return [...Array(words.length).keys()].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())[0]
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't come up with an idea of how to implement it, any ideas?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions like this here already.

Comment: You could remove the words that were correct from your list. Do this untill all words are correct then you can start over with the initial list. You could also count how much a word has come, if it surpasses a certain amount, then remove it from the list.

Comment: I can answer your question directly when I get back to a computer, but a pretty straightforward approach might be to keep a dictionary of your score (pct correct) and visits (number of times seeing) each word then compute the relative weight of each word (lots of ways to do this) - normalize the total of all the words weights to 1 them sample from a uniform distributing and select the corresponding word, ie: words A. B, and C with weights 20%,50% and 30% respectively would be selected on the following ranges: A=0-20, B=20-70, C=70-100

Comment: What I'm essentially suggesting is A/B testing where "success" is defined as you incorrectly defining the word so the bandit tries to exploit your incorrect-ness. There are several js libs that make A/B testing easy, http://aptonic.github.io/ab.js/ might be fruitful

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about `an idea of how to implement it`.

1. associate probabilities to your words
2. choose a `const value =  Math.random() * sumOfProbabilities`
3. In loop check if value is lesser than the probability of nth word, if yes return it if no decrease the value by the probability of currently checked word and move to next.

Sidenote:

```
const newIndex = () =>{
   return [...Array(words.length).keys()].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())[0]
}
```

this has a complexity of `O(nlogn)` for task that can be achieved in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following function takes your array length, a factor by which weighted indexes should appear more then none weighted and an array of all indexes which should be weighted.

```
const newWeightedRandomIndex = (length, weightedIndexes, factor) => {
    let indexArray = [...Array(length).keys()]

    //multiply the apearance of all weightedIndexes by the factor
    weightedIndexes
        .sort()
        .reverse()
        .forEach((index) => {
            let indexMultiplied = []

            for (let i = 0; i < factor; i++) {
                indexMultiplied.push(index)
            }

            indexArray = [
                ...indexArray.slice(0, index),
                ...indexMultiplied,
                ...indexArray.slice(index + 1, indexArray.length),
            ]
        })

    //get a random element of the now weighted array
    return indexArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * indexArray.length)]
}
```

So the input `newWeightedRandomIndex(4, [2,3], 3)` would generate a random index for an array with the length 4, where the indexes 2 and 3 are 3 times as likely as all other indexes to appear.

For your usecase you could call it like this:

```
let allWords = [
    { word: "Word 1", correct: false },
    { word: "Word 2", correct: false },
    { word: "Word 3", correct: true },
    { word: "Word 4", correct: false },
]

let indexesOfWordsNotAnsweredOrWrong = allWords
    .map((e, index) => ({ ...e, index })) //attach index to each
    .filter((e) => !e.correct) //filter out correct
    .map((e) => e.index) //map to only index

newWeightedRandomIndex(allWords.length, indexesOfWordsNotAnsweredOrWrong , 3)
```

So the index of each word with correct:false would be 3 times as likely to be generated.